# Create a function that produces a list of all cards that have a rank higher than base_card?

Tags: python

I have to create a function higher_in_rank that consumes a card, base_card, and produces a list of all cards which have a rank higher than base_card, sorted by increasing order of rank. The ranking of cards is as follows:

- In terms of suits, clubs are lower than diamonds, which are lower than hearts, which are lower than spades, regardless of the value.
- If two cards have the same suit, the card with the larger value has higher rank.

For example:

```
 higher_in_rank(card('spades', 8)) => [card('spades', 9), card('spades', 10)] 
 higher_in_rank(card('diamonds', 6)) =>
    [card('diamonds',7), card('diamonds', 8), ..., card('hearts',1),
    ..., card('hearts',10), card('spades', 1), ..., card('spades', 10)]
```

I have no idea where to even begin with this. I have the following:

```
class card:
    'Fields: suit, value'
    def __init__(self, suit, value):
        self.suit = suit
        self.value = value
    def __repr__(self):
        return '{suit} {value}'.format(suit=self.suit,value=self.value)
  # A card is an object card(suit, value) where
  # * suit is one of 'clubs', 'spades', 'diamonds', 'hearts', and
  # * value is an integer in the range 1..10

def higher_in_rank(base_card):
    if base_card.suit == 'clubs':
        return     #clubs, diamonds, hearts, spades
    if base_card.suit == 'diamonds':
        return     #diamonds, hearts, spades
    if base_card.suit == 'hearts':
        return     #hearts, spades
    if base_card.suit == 'spades':
        return     #spades
```

I don't know how to create the code for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would set up a sorted list of all cards, then you can quickly get all cards higher than a given card by finding the index of the given card and returning everything in the list after it.  For example:

```
class card:
    'Fields: suit, value'
    def __init__(self, suit, value):
        self.suit = suit
        self.value = value
    def __repr__(self):
        return '{suit} {value}'.format(suit=self.suit,value=self.value)
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return (isinstance(other, self.__class__) and 
                self.suit == other.suit and self.value == other.value)

all_cards = [card(s, v) 
             for s in ('clubs', 'diamonds', 'hearts', 'spades')
                 for v in range(1, 11)]

def higher_in_rank(base_card):
    return all_cards[all_cards.index(base_card)+1:]
```

Example:

```
>>> higher_in_rank(card('spades', 8))
[spades 9, spades 10]
>>> higher_in_rank(card('diamonds', 6))
[diamonds 7, diamonds 8, diamonds 9, diamonds 10, hearts 1, hearts 2, hearts 3, hearts 4, hearts 5, hearts 6, hearts 7, hearts 8, hearts 9, hearts 10, spades 1, spades 2, spades 3, spades 4, spades 5, spades 6, spades 7, spades 8, spades 9, spades 10]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would identify cards using their numeric rank, and derive the suit and value from that:

```
class Card(object):
    suits = ('clubs', 'diamonds', 'hearts', 'spades')
    values = ('2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'J', 'Q', 'K', 'A')
    def __init__(self, rank):
        self.rank = rank
    def get_suit(self):
        return Card.suits[self.rank // 13]
    def get_value(self):
        return Card.values[self.rank % 13]
    def __str__(self):
        return '{suit} {value}'.format(suit=self.get_suit(),value=self.get_value())

def higher_in_rank(base_card):
    for rank in range(base_card.rank, 52):
        yield Card(rank)

base_card = Card(0 * 13 + 5)
for card in higher_in_rank(base_card):
    print card
```